# How can i validate the input from a html5 Datalist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-datalist

I would like to know how I can validate the input value that comes from a `Datalist`. I mean, if I have a `Datalist` where the user can start to write a value and then choosing it from the `Datalist`, but the user decides to don't choose any value from the list and he submits the form with the incomplete value, the sent value will be wrong.

I thought about iterate over all the elements of the `Datalist` but I think that it can't be a good idea if the `Datalist` has more than 1.000 values and I don't know any other way to validate it.

Here is an example of the `Datalist` that I'm going to use:

```
<input type="text" list="colours">

<datalist id="colours">
    <option value="Red" data-id="1">
    <option value="Blue" data-id="2">
    <option value="Green" data-id="3">
    <option value="Black" data-id="4">
    <option value="White" data-id="5">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" list="colours" id='txt'>
```

And on form submit you can check:

```
var val = $("#txt").val();

var obj = $("#colours").find("option[value='" + val + "']");

if(obj != null && obj.length > 0)
    alert("valid");  // allow form submission
else
    alert("invalid"); // don't allow form submission
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do this with HTML5 validation using `pattern`.  It's easier if you're populating your datalist with some sort of template, but it would look something like this (Note that you would need additional code to handle the validation - I just added very simple CSS to display the validation state)

It's worth noting that this automatically blocks form submission and provides proper semantics for accessibility and other standards-compliant interoperability.

```css
input:valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
input:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" list="colours"
pattern="^(Red|Blue|Green|Black|White)$"
>

<datalist id="colours">
    <option value="Red" data-id="1">
    <option value="Blue" data-id="2">
    <option value="Green" data-id="3">
    <option value="Black" data-id="4">
    <option value="White" data-id="5">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to share a non-jquery alternative, only in Js:

```js
function is_valid_datalist_value(idDataList, inputValue) {
  var option = document.querySelector("#" + idDataList + " option[value='" + inputValue + "']");
  if (option != null) {
    return option.value.length > 0;
  }
  return false;
}

function doValidate() {
  if (is_valid_datalist_value('colours', document.getElementById('color').value)) {
    alert("Valid");
  } else {
    alert("Invalid");
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <input type="text" id="color" list="colours">
  <datalist id="colours">
    <option value="Red" data-id="1" />
    <option value="Blue" data-id="2" />
    <option value="Green" data-id="3" />
    <option value="Black" data-id="4" />
    <option value="White" data-id="5" />
    </datalist>
  <button onclick="doValidate();">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use `jQuery` [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method, it will traverse the `DOM` tree trying to find the correct element taking into account the value of one of its attributes, and looking at your comment, I think that you are concerned about performance.

Your first idea about iterate over all the options and check the value property is better (speaking about performance) than traversing the `DOM` tree looking for an element with a particular value in one of their attributes ([look at this comparison](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/4428/0/jquery-each-vs-find-attribute)). You need to be aware that *shorter code* is not the same as *faster code*.

A faster solution is to generate an `array` of strings at the beginning and search the correct value inside it in the validation process:

```
//---At the beginning of your application
let list = Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementById("colours").options, (option) => option.value);

//---Later in your validation process
if (list.indexOf(value) < 0) {
    //Invalid
}
```

Another faster solution is to generate an `object` at the beginning and use it as a [hash map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), checking for the correct value inside it in the validation process:

```
//---At the beginning of your application
let hashmap = Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.getElementById("colours").options, (obj, option) => {
    if (!obj[option.value]) { obj[option.value] = true; }
    return obj;
}, {});

//---Later in your validation process
if (!hashmap[value]) {
    //Invalid
}
```

Here you have the four methods compared in [measurethat](https://www.measurethat.net):

1 - Your first idea (iterate over all the `Datalist` options)

2 - Use the `jQuery` find method (@nsthethunderbolt solution)

3 - Create an `array` of `strings` at the beginning and search the value in the `Array` in the validation process

4 - Create a hash map at the beginning and check if the value is `true` in the validation process

https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/4430/0/search-an-option-inside-a-datalist

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, I show you a working example, which initialize an array of options:

```js
const colours = [...document.querySelectorAll('#colours option')].map( option => option.value)

document.getElementById("colour").addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  if(colours.includes(e.target.value)) {
    document.querySelector('#colour').classList.remove('invalid')
    document.querySelector('#colour').classList.add('valid')
  }
  else {
    document.querySelector('#colour').classList.remove('valid')
    document.querySelector('#colour').classList.add('invalid')
  }
})
```

```css
.valid {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
.invalid {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input id="colour" type="text" list="colours">

<datalist id="colours">
    <option value="Red" data-id="1">
    <option value="Blue" data-id="2">
    <option value="Green" data-id="3">
    <option value="Black" data-id="4">
    <option value="White" data-id="5">
</datalist>
```

Comment: a little issue is that if I use copy-and-paste a valid value, like Red, using mouse... I get red - invalid. Maybe using oninput listener can be solved.