# How to Restrict users to enter data other than option using datalist

Tags: html, html-datalist

```
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

i have used  datalist tag but problem is users are allowed to enter values other than option so how to restrict users to enter data other than options or should i use other than datalist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<datalist>` provides suggestions but [does not require that the user enter certain values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865943/html-form-select-option-vs-datalist-option).

For that, you should use a `<select>`, or something like [Selectize](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) or [Select2](https://select2.org) if you want users to type in their answers with restricted autocomplete.

It's also worth noting that `<datalist>` is brand-new and not supported by all browsers (in particular, I just tried it in Safari and it didn't work); you might consider using something else (such as the options I linked above) so that you don't restrict your website only to users with the latest standards-compliant browser.

Comment: You could use html5 validation to limit the values, ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934669/how-can-i-validate-the-input-from-a-html5-datalist

Answer (score 1):

I think the more sensible action is to make use of select form field.
More details at: [HTML Form: Select-Option vs Datalist-Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865943/html-form-select-option-vs-datalist-option)