# How can I make this a Drop down that can also search each component?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass

Greetings all and pardon my novice for I am just a mere beginner. I am looking to add a dropdown to my search bar so a user can search in the drop down. I am running into some problems because I am not sure how to do this. If any advice could be spared it would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code that pertains to this problem.

```
<div style="grid-area: jobNumber;" class="body" >
    <input type="search" class="noBorder" placeholder="Job Number">
  </div>
```

SASS

```
.body
  background-color: white
  color: $primary-text-color
  font-size: 1rem
  border: 1px solid transparentize($primary-text-color, .7)
  border-radius: .25rem
  width: 15rem
  min-height: 1rem
  padding: .375rem .75rem
  transform: scale(130%, 130%)
```

Comment: By search in the dropdown do you mean suggest search terms for the input?

Comment: Yes, so functionality wise I am looking to make a dropdown with searchable inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a dropdown that recommends options you could add a [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) element and link it to your input:

```html
<div style="grid-area: jobNumber;" class="body" >
    <input type="search" class="noBorder" list="your-datalist-name" placeholder="Job Number">
</div>
<!-- the ID here and list attribute on your input link the two together -->
<datalist id="your-datalist-name">
  <option value="job1">
  <option value="job2">
  <!-- etc... -->
</datalist>
```

If you want to *restrict* users to your list of values, [see this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49166815/how-to-restrict-users-to-enter-data-other-than-option-using-datalist)

Comment: Yep. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the very useful answer Zach.