# Searchable select in Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

In Bootstrap 3 you had the option to add the attribute
`data-live-search="true"` to enable [live search](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#customize-menu).

How can I implement this feature in Bootstrap 5?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use what is known as a [Datalist](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/#datalists) in Bootstrap5 to achieve that. It works almost exactly like the Live Search that you mentioned

Comment: The problem with this is that if for example i select New York and click the dropdown again only New York will appear. Is there a way to just keep everything in the list?

Comment: For that you need to dynamically change each of the options in the datalist after 'New York' has been selected

Comment: You can use html5 validation to make sure the provided input is limited to the values in the datalist: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934669/how-can-i-validate-the-input-from-a-html5-datalist

Comment: If you didn't find the searchable select for bootstrap5 here is one mdbootstrap.com but it doesn't work

Comment: Not working in android Firefox, see detail: https://caniuse.com/datalist

Comment: Actually this is not really matching the expected behavior. Datalists allow users to enter a custom value that do not belong to the option list which is not the case for selects. You would have to write some custom JS on top of it to match the behavior or use an external component like some other users point out.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [choice-js](https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices)

With an example, taken from adminkit.io:

```js
new Choices(document.querySelector(".choices-single"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/choices.js@9.0.1/public/assets/styles/choices.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/choices.js@9.0.1/public/assets/scripts/choices.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control choices-single">
  <option></option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
  <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
  <option value="MT">Montana</option>
  <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
  <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
  <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
  <option value="UT">Utah</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer actually it's closer to what the user asked

Comment: choice-js hasn't been maintained in years.